# Scanning translatable strings in zend 3 forms with Poedit

Tags: forms, zend-framework3, poedit

Zend 3 translates form labels automatically.

1. If forms are created using array specification, how is it possible to scan translatable form element strings with Poedit?
2. How to add translator->translate() functionality to forms? I tried the following in module.php onBootstrap method but this does not work:

   ```
   $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager(); 
   $vhm = $sm->get('ViewHelperManager'); 
   $translator = $sm->get('MvcTranslator');  
   $vhm->get('form')->setTranslator($translator);
   ```

I want to use it like $form->translator->translate(), in such a way it would be possible to scan code with Poedit to find translatable labeles, placeholders etc.

Comment: Translator works well for forms. You just have to add your files nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a TranslatorFactory if you need

```
final class TranslatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
     public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
     {
           // get translator files' paths from config
           $paths      = $container->get('config')['settings']['localization-paths'] ?? [];
           $translator = new Translator();

           // add zend-i18n-resources files to translator
           $translator->addTranslationFilePattern(
              'phpArray',
               Resources::getBasePath(),
               Resources::getPatternForValidator()
          );

          // add your translation files to translator
          foreach ($paths as $path) {
               $translator->addTranslationFilePattern('phpArray', $path, '%s.php');
          }

          // todo: replace with user's preferred language
          $translator->setLocale('tr');

          return $translator;
      }
}
```

And add your factory to service manager

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface::class => \MyModule\Factory\TranslatorFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thank you Mehmet! Your solution does not say how I can use translator for form elements. I need this for scanning code with Poedit to find all translatable phrases. How to tell Poedit what to look for?

Comment: You don't need anything to do forms use translator. ZF uses translator automatically. You just need to add zend-mvc-i18n to your project. Rest is same with my answer except "phpArray" you will change it with "gettext"

Comment: Thanks again! I know that ZF3 translates form labels automatically but I do not understand how I can scan all module  files to find all translatables and generate .mo files. I know how to do this with Poedit when pattern is translate(’something’).

Comment: If you wish to scan all modules you have to check ModuleManager. It has "getModules" and "getLoadedModules" methods. But you don't have to use it. Your modules can simply return language files' paths in their config. I'm doing exacly this in my example. Each module has a key as "localization-paths" in their config's and localization files in those paths as "de.php", "ru.php" etc.

Comment: My question still – how to generate the „dictionary“ en.php(en.po), de.php(de.po) files? In order to generate the „dictionary“ en.po(php), de.po(php) files I ususally scan full module code with Poedit. Poedit can be configured to recognize translatable strings, for example _(), translate() or ohter patterns. Form labels in array  specification  do not have the pattern that could be configured in Poedit (at least I do not know how to do it). 
I do not want manually collect translatable strings during coding, I need to generate the „dictionary“ files after the module is ready.

Comment: Oh, I've didn't use poedit but you may want to check this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149213

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution, so I'll add mine.

I use the `TranslatorAwareTrait` in my `AbstractForm` class.

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorAwareTrait;

abstract class AbstractForm extends \Zend\Form\Form implements
{
    use TranslatorAwareTrait;
    
    // Form stuff
}
```

Then, in the `*FormFactory` do the following:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class SomeFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return mixed|object|AbstractForm
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Obviously you'll have more/other requirements. Fulfil them here.
        $form = new SomeForm();
        $form->setTranslator(
            $container->get('translator')
        );

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorAwareTrait;

abstract class AbstractForm extends \Zend\Form\Form implements 
{
    use TranslatorAwareTrait;

    public function init()
    {
        if (!$this->has('submit')) {
            $this->addSubmitButton();
        }
    }

    public function addSubmitButton($value = 'Save', array $classes = null)
    {
        $this->add([
            'name'       => 'submit',
            'type'       => Submit::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 
                    // Translate $value before passing to this function
                    $value === 'Save' ? $this->getTranslator()->translate('Save') : $value, 
                'class' => (!is_null($classes) ? join (' ', $classes) : 'btn btn-primary'),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

#### On the other hand, you could...

Translate strings before passing them if you're translating with Poedit.

If your modules contain the following config (in each module!):

```
'translator' => [
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

You can see here that translation is done using `gettext`. This is a PHP module that searches for the following code strings and translates its contents: `_('translatable string')`.

The translation files to look for end with the `.mo` extension and can be found in `__DIR__ . '/../language'`.

Thus, if you make sure to have the PHP [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) module enabled to use this.

To use this with just normal strings, even in config for a Fieldset or a form, you could have the following:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'street',
    'required' => true,
    'type' => Text::class,
    'options' => [
        'label' => _('Street'), // <<-- translated using gettext
    ],
]);
```